# Xcode 6: Set Preprocessor Macros per architecture

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, objective-c++

I would like to learn how to properly configure an Xcode iOS project so that I can specify different **Preprocessor Macros** per **architecture**. The C++ libraries that my project relies on want a flag set to tell them if they are running on a 32-bit or 64-bit platform.

Since Apple now requires all submissions to be both 32-bit and 64-bit, I can no longer get by using ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT and just using a single 32-bit configuration.

It seems that the Xcode UI will only let me specify macros per build type (Debug/Release). And I haven't found a specific solution on developer.apple.com.

Is there a way that I can specify these definitions in the compiler?

Do I need to use a prefix header instead? If so, are there any best practices?

Does anybody out there have a magical CMAKE configuration that will solve all my problems?

My goal is to have a configuration that works cleanly in both the simulator and on the device.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select Preprocessor Macros, you can select different values for Release and Debug. When you put cursor on Release or Debug you will notice + button. Clicking on that + button you will be able to choose architecture for which you want to specify macro.
[image]

===================================================================

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Sergio. I can't believe I missed that.